# How to change Toolbar height and font size programmatically depending of text length

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a lot of different titles for `Toolbar` that I pass from previous activity trough intent:

```
title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```

And I set them to my Toolbar of new activity like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

But the font is too large and only covers one line of toolbar:
[image]

This is one of the example titles:
CONVERSION OF RADAR RANGE PROPAGATION KILOMETER INTO MICROSECOND TIME AND VICE-VERSA

I would like to know is there a way to dynamically change `Toolbar` height and text size to fit this titles? Can this be done programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this create custom toolbar like this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Did you know"
            android:id="@+id/myTitle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**and use theme of your activity as NoActionBar**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView myTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?
Also I need to get font size smaller when there is a longer text...

Comment: I will use your answer, because I didn't managed to make it programmatically and  I adopted my code to this. Also the font now is smaller and it can always fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in java file;

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```